# Load and refresh JSON dataset from REST API using desktop tool

Tags: json, xml, csv, etl, webtrends

Currently, I query WebTrends API to download data into Excel. However, now I am searching for a more reliable method/tool for getting hold of the data in JSON/XML format, then convert it to CSV in order to use it in a variety of data stores and analysis tools.

It would be a bonus if the tool can automate an update to the feed on regular intervals by appending new data to existing datasets.

Oh it needs to be Free/Opensource.

My research led me to ETL tools like Talend,  JaspersoftETL and CloverETL...etc. But I am struggling to determine if they can do the job and which one is easier! Does anyone know how to achieve the above job in an 1-free 2-easy 3-lightweight manner?

WebTrends API URL looks like this:  http://ws.webtrends.com/v2_1/ReportService/profiles/dnGpm8jbgl7/reports/1RxjilSo4n7/?totals=none&period=2017m02d27*26&format=json&suppress_error_codes=true

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Ruby, then [Kiba ETL](http://www.kiba-etl.org/) is a lightweight free OSS solution which you can use for that type of scenarios.

Typically the code will look like:

```rb
source YourJSONHTTPDownloadSource, urls: [url_1, url_2]

transform do |row|
  # remap the fields as needed
  row
end

destination YourCSVDestination, filename: my_filename
```

And you would run it using the Kiba command line.

You will have to write `YourJSONHTTPDownloadSource` (a Kiba source to fetch the data from the url and yield each JSON/XML element) and `YourCSVDestination` (for more details on that, check out the [readme](https://github.com/thbar/kiba/blob/master/README.md)).

PS: the URL your provided requires authentication, which means we cannot see anything.